# Can I read line from a heredoc in bash?

Tags: bash, heredoc

Here's what I'm trying. What I want is the last `echo` to say "one two three four test1..." as it loops. It's not working; `read line` is coming up empty. Is there something subtle here or is this just not going to work?

```
array=( one two three )
echo ${array[@]}
#one two three
array=( ${array[@]} four )
echo ${array[@]}
#one two three four


while read line; do
        array=( ${array[@]} $line )
        echo ${array[@]}
done < <( echo <<EOM
test1
test2
test3
test4
EOM
)
```

Comment: `array+=("four")` and `array+=("$line")`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would normally write:

```
while read line
do
    array=( ${array[@]} $line )
    echo ${array[@]}
done <<EOM
test1
test2
test3
test4
EOM
```

Or, even more likely:

```
cat <<EOF |
test1
test2
test3
test4
EOF

while read line
do
    array=( ${array[@]} $line )
    echo ${array[@]}
done
```

(Note that the version with a pipe will not necessarily be suitable in Bash.  The Bourne shell would run the `while` loop in the current shell, but Bash runs it in a subshell — at least by default.  In the Bourne shell, the assignments made in the loop would be available in the main shell after the loop; in Bash, they are not.  The first version always sets the array variable so it is available for use after the loop.)

You could also use:

```
array+=( $line )
```

to add to the array.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
done < <( echo <<EOM
```

with

```
done < <(cat << EOM
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the command in front of while instead:

```
(echo <<EOM
test1
test2
test3
test4
EOM
) | while read line; do
        array=( ${array[@]} $line )
        echo ${array[@]}
done
```

Comment: And as sha says, cat is probably more appropriate than echo here.