# Loop over tuples in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

Is it possible to loop over tuples in Bash?

As an example, it would be great if the following worked:

```
for (i,j) in ((c,3), (e,5)); do echo "$i and $j"; done
```

Is there a workaround that somehow lets me loop over tuples?

Comment: Coming from python background this is a very useful question indeed!

Comment: looking at this four years later I wonder if there is still no better way of doing this. omg.

Comment: Almost 8 years later I also wondered if there is still no better way of doing this. But this 2018 answer looks pretty good to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228219/463994

Answer (score 108):

```
$ for i in c,3 e,5; do IFS=","; set -- $i; echo $1 and $2; done
c and 3
e and 5
```

About this use of `set` (from `man builtins`):

> Any arguments  remaining after option processing are treated as values
> for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1,  $2,
> ...   $n

The `IFS=","` sets the field separator so every `$i` gets segmented into `$1` and `$2` correctly.

Via [this blog](http://bergmanlab.smith.man.ac.uk/?p=525).

A more correct version, as suggested by @SLACEDIAMOND:

```
$ OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=','; for i in c,3 e,5; do set -- $i; echo $1 and $2; done; IFS=$OLDIFS
c and 3
e and 5
```

Comment: Nice -- just want to point out `IFS` should be saved and reset to its original value if this is run on the command line.  Also, the new `IFS` can be set once, before the loop runs, rather than every iteration.

Comment: In case any of the $i starts with a hyphen, it's safer to `set -- $i`

Comment: Instead of saving `IFS`, only set it for the `set` command: `for i in c,3 e,5; do IFS="," set -- $i; echo $1 and $2; done`. Please edit your answer: If all readers would choose only one of the listed solutions, there's no sense in having to read the full development history. Thanks for this cool trick!

Comment: If I declare `tuples="a,1 b,2 c,3"` and put `IFS=','` as in the edited version , and instead of `c,3 e,5` use `$tuples` it doesn't print well at all.
But instead if I put `IFS=','` just after the `do` keyword in the for loop, it works well when using `$tuples` as well as litteral values. Just thought it was worth saying.

Comment: @Simonlbc that's because the for loop uses `IFS` to split iterations. i.e. If you loop over an array like `arr=("c,3" "e,5")` and put `IFS` before the for loop, the value of `$i` will be just `c` and `e`, it will split away `3` and `5` so `set` won't parse correctly because `$i` won't have anything to parse. This mean that if the values to iterate are not inlined, the `IFS` should be put inside the loop, and the outside value should respect the intended separator for the variable to iterate upon. In the cases of `$tuples` it should be simply `IFS=` which is default and splits upon whitespace.

Answer (score 79):

Based on the [answer given by Eduardo Ivanec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713104/loop-over-tuples-in-bash/9713142#9713142) without setting/resetting the [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_Field_Separators), one could simply do:

```
for i in "c 3" "e 5"
do
    set -- $i # Convert the "tuple" into the param args $1 $2...
    echo $1 and $2
done
```

The output:

```
c and 3
e and 5
```

Comment: This approach seems to me a lot simpler than the accepted and most-upvoted approach. Is there any reason not to do it this way as opposed to what @Eduardo Ivanec suggested?

Comment: @spurra this answer is 6 years and ½ more recent, and based on it. Credit where it's due.

Comment: @Diego I am aware of that. It's explicitly written in the answer. I was asking if there is any reason not to use this approach over the accepted answer.

Comment: @spurra you'd want to use Eduardo's answer if the default separator (space, tab or newline) doesn't work for you for some reason (https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS)

Comment: What would you do if you already have a `$1`, `$2` being utilized within your function because you're passing parameters? i.e. how do you distinguish between the 1st & 2nd parameter passed on vs. the 1st & 2nd item of the tuples?

Comment: IFS stands for internal field separator. Based on IFS `set` splits the string. https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF

Comment: Isn't "param args" redundant?

Answer (score 56):

[This](https://github.com/bahamas10/bash-style-guide#read-builtin) Bash style guide illustrates how `read` can be used to split strings at a delimiter and assign them to individual variables.  So using that technique you can parse the string and assign the variables with a one liner like the one in the loop below:

```bash
for i in c,3 e,5; do
    IFS=',' read item1 item2 <<< "${i}"
    echo "${item1}" and "${item2}"
done
```

Comment: Nice. `read -r` is even better, so backslashes are left as is: `for i in 'c,\3' e,5; do IFS=',' read -r item1 item2 <<< "${i}"; done`

Answer (score 21):

Use an associative array (also known as a dictionary and hashMap):

```
animals=(dog cat mouse)
declare -A sound=(
  [dog]=barks
  [cat]=purrs
  [mouse]=cheeps
)
declare -A size=(
  [dog]=big
  [cat]=medium
  [mouse]=small
)
for animal in "${animals[@]}"; do
  echo "$animal ${sound[$animal]} and it is ${size[$animal]}"
done
```

Comment: FYI, this didn't work for me on Mac with `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)`, which was installed via brew, so YMMV.

Comment: it did however work on `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` from Ubuntu 14.04 within docker container.

Comment: seems like older versions of bash or ones not supporting this feature work off index basing? where the key is a number rather than string. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html, and instead of `-A` we have `-a`.

Comment: David, seems so. I think you can try array indices to get "associativity" then. Like `declare -a indices=(1 2 3); declare -a sound=(barks purrs cheeps); declare -a size=(big medium small)` etc. Haven't tried it in terminal yet, but I think it should work.

Comment: It appears associative array order of iterating over keys is random, so be careful...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161323/how-to-keep-associative-array-order

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks! I've removed the part of my answer that dealt with non-deterministic iteration order, and the current solution should always iterate exactly as you defined it.

Answer (score 9):

```
c=('a' 'c')
n=(3    4 )

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#c[*]}-1)))
do
    echo ${c[i]} ${n[i]}
done
```

Might sometimes be more handy.

To explain the `ugly` part, as noted in the comments:

**seq 0 2** produces the sequence of numbers 0 1 2. $(cmd) is command substitution, so for this example the output of `seq 0 2`, which is the number sequence. But what is the upper bound, the `$((${#c[*]}-1))`?

$((somthing)) is arithmetic expansion, so $((3+4)) is 7 etc. Our Expression is `${#c[*]}-1`, so something - 1. Pretty simple, if we know what `${#c[*]}` is.

c is an array, c[*] is just the whole array, ${#c[*]} is the size of the array which is 2 in our case. Now we roll everything back: `for i in $(seq 0 $((${#c[*]}-1)))` is `for i in $(seq 0 $((2-1)))` is `for i in $(seq 0 1)` is `for i in 0 1`. Because the last element in the array has an index which is the length of the Array - 1.

Comment: you should do `for i in $(seq 0 $(($#c[*]}-1))); do [...]`

Comment: Wow, this wins the “Ugliest Bunch of Arbitrary Characters I've Seen Today” award. Anyone care to explain what exactly this abomination does? I got lost at the hash sign...

Comment: @koniiiik: Explanation added.

Comment: "Neu-Perl:  The Revenge"   I think it would actually be clearer in perl.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

But what if the tuple is greater than the k/v that an associative array can hold? What if it's 3 or 4 elements? One could expand on this concept:

```
###---------------------------------------------------
### VARIABLES
###---------------------------------------------------
myVars=(
    'ya1,ya2,ya3,ya4'
    'ye1,ye2,ye3,ye4'
    'yo1,yo2,yo3,yo4'
    )


###---------------------------------------------------
### MAIN PROGRAM
###---------------------------------------------------
### Echo all elements in the array
###---
printf '\n\n%s\n' "Print all elements in the array..."
for dataRow in "${myVars[@]}"; do
    while IFS=',' read -r var1 var2 var3 var4; do
        printf '%s\n' "$var1 - $var2 - $var3 - $var4"
    done <<< "$dataRow"
done
```

Then the output would look something like:

```
$ ./assoc-array-tinkering.sh 

Print all elements in the array...
ya1 - ya2 - ya3 - ya4
ye1 - ye2 - ye3 - ye4
yo1 - yo2 - yo3 - yo4
```

And the number of elements are now without limit. Not looking for votes; just thinking out loud. [REF1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005), [REF2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Input_source_selection)

Comment: This one works for sh. Since newer version of macOS stops keeping update bash, this once is more suitable for scripts targeting macOS.

Comment: There are a few bourn-like shells worth exploring: 1) bash (more feature-rich than the original), 2) dash (posix-compliant version of the original). For EVERY new macOS install, I would recommend `brew install shellcheck bash dash bash-completion@2`. This will get the latest GNU bash - just like on Linux; so everything is the same everywhere :-)

Comment: The bash completion is only necessary if you're still using bash as the system shell `echo $SHELL` find out. On a new macOS it should be ZSH; in that case, do yourself a favor and install Oh My ZSH - it's just superior.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ echo 'c,3;e,5;' | while IFS=',' read -d';' i j; do echo "$i and $j"; done
c and 3
e and 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel):

```
parallel echo {1} and {2} ::: c e :::+ 3 5
```

Or:

```
parallel -N2 echo {1} and {2} ::: c 3 e 5
```

Or:

```
parallel --colsep , echo {1} and {2} ::: c,3 e,5
```

Comment: No love for this?  well made *me* overcome inertia and install `gnu parallel`

Comment: `brew install parallel`

Comment: Perhaps the affiliation should be revealed? E.g., from *[How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)*: *"you* ***must*** *disclose your affiliation in your post"*. See also *[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/)*, *[How to treat open source repository promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339640/)*, *[What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361284/)*, -

Comment: cont' - *[Is this library promotion spamming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276392/)*, and *[Self-promotion abuse detected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252811/self-promotion-abuse-detected)*.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read key value
do echo $key $value
done < file_discriptor
```

For example:

```
$ while read key value; do echo $key $value ;done <<EOF
> c 3
> e 5
> EOF
c 3
e 5

$ echo -e 'c 3\ne 5' > file

$ while read key value; do echo $key $value ;done <file
c 3
e 5

$ echo -e 'c,3\ne,5' > file

$ while IFS=, read key value; do echo $key $value ;done <file
c 3
e 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `printf` in a process substitution:

```
while read -r k v; do
    echo "Key $k has value: $v"
done < <(printf '%s\n' 'key1 val1' 'key2 val2' 'key3 val3')
```

```
Key key1 has value: val1
Key key2 has value: val2
Key key3 has value: val3
```

Above requires `bash`. If `bash` is not being used then use simple pipeline:

```
printf '%s\n' 'key1 val1' 'key2 val2' 'key3 val3' |
while read -r k v; do echo "Key $k has value: $v"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases where my tuple definitions are more complex, I prefer to have them in a heredoc:

```
while IFS=", " read -ra arr; do
  echo "${arr[0]} and ${arr[1]}"
done <<EOM
c, 3
e, 5
EOM
```

This combines [looping over lines of a heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337686/1804173) with [splitting the lines at some desired separating character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263615/1804173).

Answer (score 0):

A bit more involved, but may be useful:

```
a='((c,3), (e,5))'
IFS='()'; for t in $a; do [ -n "$t" ] && { IFS=','; set -- $t; [ -n "$1" ] && echo i=$1 j=$2; }; done
```