# How to read and split comma separated file in a bash shell script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, split

I want to read a file line by line, split each line by comma (,) and store the result in an array. How to do this in a bash shell script?

Sample line in my comma separated file

```
123,2014-07-21 10:01:44,123|8119|769.00||456|S
```

This should be the output after splitting:

```
arr[0]=123 arr[1]=2014-07-21 10:01:44 arr[2]=123|8119|769.00||456|S
```

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple lines? Would the first field of the second line be placed in `arr[3]`? Or does the array only need to hold one line at a time, being reset on each iteration?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `read -a` to split each line read into array based from IFS.

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    ## Do something with ${arr0]}, ${arr[1]} and ${arr[2]}
    ...
done < file
```

If the third field can also contain commas, you can prevent it from being split by using finite non-array parameters:

```
while IFS=, read -r a b c; do
    ## Do something with $a, $b and $c
    ...
done < file
```

From `help read`:

> ```
> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
> if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
> splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
> word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
> the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
> delimiters.
>
>   -a array  assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
>             variable ARRAY, starting at zero
> ```