# Line manipulation & sorting

Tags: string, bash, sorting, tshark

I am alright at writing Linux scripts but could use some advice. I know the problem is sort of vague, so if you can provide any help whatsoever I will appreciate it!

The following issue is for personal growth, and because I am writing some network tools for fun/learning. No homework involved (I'm a senior in college, none of my classes require this stuff!)

I am using tshark to get information about packet captures. This is what it looks like:

```
rachel@Ubuntu-1:~/PCAP$ tshark -r LargeTorrent.pcap -q -z io,phs

===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter: 

eth                                      frames:4309 bytes:3984321
  ip                                     frames:4119 bytes:3969006
    icmp                                 frames:1316 bytes:1308988
    udp                                  frames:1408 bytes:1350786
      data                               frames:1368 bytes:1346228
      dns                                frames:16 bytes:1176
      nbns                               frames:14 bytes:1300
      http                               frames:8 bytes:1596
      nbdgm                              frames:2 bytes:486
        smb                              frames:2 bytes:486
          mailslot                       frames:2 bytes:486
            browser                      frames:2 bytes:486
    tcp                                  frames:1395 bytes:1309232
      data                               frames:1300 bytes:1294800
      http                               frames:6 bytes:3763
        data-text-lines                  frames:2 bytes:324
        xml                              frames:2 bytes:3205
          tcp.segments                   frames:1 bytes:787
      nbss                               frames:34 bytes:5863
        smb                              frames:17 bytes:3047
          pipe                           frames:4 bytes:686
            lanman                       frames:4 bytes:686
        smb2                             frames:13 bytes:2444
      bittorrent                         frames:10 bytes:1709
        tcp.segments                     frames:2 bytes:433
          bittorrent                     frames:2 bytes:433
            bittorrent                   frames:1 bytes:258
        bittorrent                       frames:2 bytes:221
          bittorrent                     frames:2 bytes:221
  arp                                    frames:146 bytes:8760
  ipv6                                   frames:44 bytes:6555
    udp                                  frames:40 bytes:6211
      dns                                frames:18 bytes:1711
      dhcpv6                             frames:14 bytes:2114
      http                               frames:6 bytes:1014
      data                               frames:2 bytes:1372
    icmpv6                               frames:4 bytes:344
===================================================================
```

What I would like for it to look like:

```
rachel@Ubuntu-1:~/PCAP$ tshark -r LargeTorrent.pcap -q -z io,phs

===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter: 

Protocol                   Bytes
=====================================
eth                        984321
  ip                       3969006
    icmp                   1308988
    udp                    1350786
      data                 1346228
      dns                  1176
      nbns                 1300
      http                 1596
      nbdgm                486
        smb                486
          mailslot         486
            browser        486
    tcp                    1309232
      data                 1294800
      http                 3763
        data-text-lines    324
        xml                3205
          tcp.segments     787
      nbss                 5863
        smb                3047
          pipe             686
            lanman         686
        smb2               2444
      bittorrent           1709
        tcp.segments       433
          bittorrent       433
            bittorrent     258
        bittorrent         221
          bittorrent       221
  arp                      8760
  ipv6                     6555
    udp                    6211
      dns                  1711
      dhcpv6               2114
      http                 1014
      data                 1372
    icmpv6                 344
===================================================================
```

---

---

---

Edit: I am going to add the original question for the purpose of making sense of the (great) answer that was provided.

Originally, I wanted to only print statistics for "leaves" because eth, ip, etc. are all parents and their statistics are not necessary for my purposes. In addition, instead of having a god-awful block of text with only spaces to show hierarchy, I wanted to erase all the statistics for parents, and show them as breadcrumbs behind the child.

Example:

```
eth                                      frames:4309 bytes:3984321
  ip                                     frames:4119 bytes:3969006
    icmp                                 frames:1316 bytes:1308988
    udp                                  frames:1408 bytes:1350786
      data                               frames:1368 bytes:1346228
      dns                                frames:16 bytes:1176
```

Should become

```
eth:ip:icmp - 1308988 bytes
eth:ip:udp:data - 1346228 bytes
eth:ip:udp:dns - 1176 bytes
```

To preserve the hierarchy and avoid printing useless statistics.

Anyway, the approved answer by Etan solved this perfectly! And for those of you who are on my level who are unsure of how to proceed after this answer, this will help you finish up:

1. Save the given script as a `filename.awk` file
2. Save the block of text you want to manipulate as a `filename.txt` file
3. Call `awk -f filename.awk filename.txt`
4. Optionally pipe the output to a file ( `awk -f filename.awk filename.txt >> output.txt` )

Comment: What do you want to do with the non-leaf byte counts (e.g. The count for `eth.ip` or the count for `eth.ipv6.udp`)?

Comment: Very good question! I wasn't sure how to describe it (non-leaf items, that is). I am alright with having them show up - I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is realistic to accomplish, and I don't imagine the non-leaf ones can just be thrown out. I also don't imagine that I can sort by byte count, because then parent/children items would no longer be nested correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's not at all the output I thought you meant. I thought you literally meant `:` separated hierarchy names on each line. That output is much simpler than what I thought (and just finished with). =)

Comment: Yes, I know it was confusing. Essentially after reading over what I "wanted" and then considering what I wanted my end product to do, I figured it wouldn't hurt to simplify the line manipulation.

I did initially think a colon could separate hierarchy names, but of course realized that it wasn't such a great idea & that it wasn't at all necessary for the purposes I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output I originally thought you wanted could be achieved with this `awk` script. (I think this can probably be done cleaner but this seems to work well enough.)

```
function entry() {
    # Don't want to print empty entries.
    if (ind[0]) {
        printf "%s", ind[0]
        for (i = 1; i <= ls; i++) {
            printf ":%s", ind[i]
        }
        split(b, a, /:/)
        printf " - %s %s\n", a[2], a[1]
    }
}

# Found our data marker. Note that and print the current line.
$1 == "Filter:" {d=1; print; next}
# Print lines until we see our data marker.
!d {print; next}
# Print empty lines.
!NF {print; next}
# Save our trailing line for later.
/===/ {suf=$0; next}

{
    # Save our previous indentation level.
    ls = s
    # Find our new indentation level (by where the first field starts).
    s = (match($0, /[^[:space:]]/)-1) / 2

    # If the current line is at or below the last indent level print the last line.
    if (s <= ls) {
        entry()
    }

    # Save the current line's byte count.
    b=$NF
    # Save the current line's field name.
    ind[s] = $1
}

END {
    # Print a final line if we had one.
    entry()
    # Print the suffix line if we have one.
    if (suf) {
        print suf
    }
}
```

Which, on the sample input, gets you this output.

```
===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter:

eth:ip:icmp - 1308988 bytes
eth:ip:udp:data - 1346228 bytes
eth:ip:udp:dns - 1176 bytes
eth:ip:udp:nbns - 1300 bytes
eth:ip:udp:http - 1596 bytes
eth:ip:udp:nbdgm:smb:mailslot:browser - 486 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:data - 1294800 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:http:data-text-lines - 324 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:http:xml:tcp.segments - 787 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:nbss:smb:pipe:lanman - 686 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:nbss:smb2 - 2444 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:bittorrent:tcp.segments:bittorrent:bittorrent - 258 bytes
eth:ip:tcp:bittorrent:bittorrent:bittorrent - 221 bytes
eth:arp - 8760 bytes
eth:ipv6:udp:dns - 1711 bytes
eth:ipv6:udp:dhcpv6 - 2114 bytes
eth:ipv6:udp:http - 1014 bytes
eth:ipv6:udp:data - 1372 bytes
eth:ipv6:icmpv6:data - 344 bytes
===================================================================
```

Output like what you edited to indicate you want is probably more easily handled with `sed` though.

```
/Filter:/a \
Protocol                   Bytes \
=====================================
s/frames:[^ ]*//
s/               b/b/
s/bytes:\([^ ]*\)/\1/
```

Which ends up with output.

```
===================================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter:
Protocol                   Bytes
=====================================

eth                        3984321
  ip                       3969006
    icmp                   1308988
    udp                    1350786
      data                 1346228
      dns                  1176
      nbns                 1300
      http                 1596
      nbdgm                486
        smb                486
          mailslot         486
            browser        486
    tcp                    1309232
      data                 1294800
      http                 3763
        data-text-lines    324
        xml                3205
          tcp.segments     787
      nbss                 5863
        smb                3047
          pipe             686
            lanman         686
        smb2               2444
      bittorrent           1709
        tcp.segments       433
          bittorrent       433
            bittorrent     258
        bittorrent         221
          bittorrent       221
  arp                      8760
  ipv6                     6555
    udp                    6211
      dns                  1711
      dhcpv6               2114
      http                 1014
      data                 1372
    icmpv6                 344
===================================================================
```

Comment: Wow, you are truly an expert. Thank you so much for your assistance! Absolutely perfect answer.

To other readers: I edited the question thinking that it was unreasonable, but Etan provided an answer to the original AND the edited question.

Comment: Also, to note for anyone else who ends up on this post - modifying the command to be `awk -f protocols.awk protocols.txt | tail -n +6 | sort -r -n -k3` will cut out all the unnecessary header stuff, as well as sort in descending order of bytes.

Comment: Dropping the header stuff in the awk script is easy. In fact a lot of the ugliness at the beginning is in making sure we don't do that. Drop `print` from the one-line bits near the top and that should do it. And yeah, I forgot about the sorting part but that `sort` command is what I would have gone with (though it could be done in awk too if you wanted to).

Answer (score 2):

A simple script with `sed` will work as well.

```
$ printf "\n==========================================================\n"; printf "Protocol Hierarchy Statistics\nFilter:\n\n";printf "\nProtocol\t\t\t\t Bytes\n================================================\n" && sed -e 's/\(frames[:].*bytes[:]\)\(.*$\)/\2/' dat/tshark.txt | tail -n+4 | head -n-1 && printf "================================================\n"
```

broken down into script form (where `dat/tshark.txt` is the filename holding the `tshark` output):

```
printf "\n==========================================================\n"
printf "Protocol Hierarchy Statistics\nFilter:\n\n"
printf "\nProtocol\t\t\t\t Bytes\n================================================\n"
sed -e 's/\(frames[:].*bytes[:]\)\(.*$\)/\2/' dat/tshark.txt | tail -n+4 | head -n-1
printf "================================================\n"
```

**Output**

```
==========================================================
Protocol Hierarchy Statistics
Filter:

Protocol                                 Bytes
================================================

eth                                      3984321
  ip                                     3969006
    icmp                                 1308988
    udp                                  1350786
      data                               1346228
      dns                                1176
      nbns                               1300
      http                               1596
      nbdgm                              486
        smb                              486
          mailslot                       486
            browser                      486
    tcp                                  1309232
      data                               1294800
      http                               3763
        data-text-lines                  324
        xml                              3205
          tcp.segments                   787
      nbss                               5863
        smb                              3047
          pipe                           686
            lanman                       686
        smb2                             2444
      bittorrent                         1709
        tcp.segments                     433
          bittorrent                     433
            bittorrent                   258
        bittorrent                       221
          bittorrent                     221
  arp                                    8760
  ipv6                                   6555
    udp                                  6211
      dns                                1711
      dhcpv6                             2114
      http                               1014
      data                               1372
    icmpv6                               344
================================================
```

---

### Formatting

Following on from your comment on how to align the `bytes` info given the variable length of the `protocol tags`, you can make use of `printf` to format the output as you have indicated. Like Ethan, I started working on your original question that had the tags consolidated. My initial approach was to read the different levels into different **associative arrays** that could be combined into what you initially specified. Doing so, I had to produce the output lined up using `printf`. Here is the first attempt I made working with the first 4-levels of your tshark data:

```
declare -i ln=0
declare -A l1 l2 l3 l4

## read each line in file and assing to associative arrays for each level
while read -r line; do

    ln=${#line}   # base level on length of line read
    [ $ln -gt 66 ] && continue;
    [ $ln -eq 66 ] && { iface="${line%% *}"; l1[${iface}]="${line##*  }"; }
    [ $ln -eq 64 ] && { proto="${iface}:${line%% *}"; l2[${proto}]="${line##*  }"; }
    [ $ln -eq 62 ] && { ptype="${proto}:${line%% *}"; l3[${ptype}]="${line##*  }"; }
    [ $ln -le 60 ] && { data="${ptype}:${line%% *}"; l4[${data}]="${line##*  }"; }

done < "$1"

## output a summary of the file
printf "\n4-level deep summary of file '%s':\n\n" "$1"
for i in "${!l1[@]}"; do
    for j in "${!l2[@]}"; do
        printf "  %-32s    %s\n" "$j" "${l2[$j]}"
        for k in "${!l3[@]}"; do
            printf "  %-32s    %s\n" "$k" "${l3[$k]}"
            for l in "${!l4[@]}"; do
                [ "${l%:*}" == "$k" ] && printf "  %-32s    %s\n" "$l" "${l4[$l]}"
            done
        done
    done
done
```

The output it produced was for example:

```
eth:ip                              frames:4119 bytes:3969006
eth:ip:udp                          frames:1408 bytes:1350786
eth:ip:udp:data                     frames:1368 bytes:1346228
eth:ip:udp:nbdgm                    frames:2 bytes:486
eth:ip:udp:nbns                     frames:14 bytes:1300
```

You can look at the various `printf` statements in the code above and see how the alignment is handled. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Wow thanks for your help! You seem to know a lot about this stuff.

So if I had my lines formatted like this (eth:ip:icmp - 1308988 bytes), is there a way I could tab out all the byte counts to be flush?

I wish I could describe better but the comment formatting is messing me up!

Comment: Yes, I did a little bit in the example above. If using bash, `printf` gives you far more control over formatting that does `echo`. You essentially have the same format specifier available in bash as you do in C. What I did when I worked on your question before the edit, was to come up with a `printf` similar to `printf "%-32s   %s bytes\n" "$proto" "$bytes"` where `proto` holds (e.g. `eth:ip:icmp`) and `bytes` holds `1308988`. Is that similar to what you are looking for? I'll edit the answer and add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised that tshark doesn't have a JSON or machine-readable way to get the -z io,phs info, when it has so many ways to extract packet info.

I tried playing with some of the above, but **bash** seems to have changed over the years (or has different defaults depending on the environment). I am also not sure which shell or version of it was used to produce the above.

The line lengths/output from tshark have also changed: My debugging showed different line lengths, so the trick above using line lengths, e.g. `[ $ln -gt 66 ]` didn't work for me.

1. It seems that `read -r` strips out leading/trailing whitespaces. If you actually want it, you need IFS= to make it give you the spaces:

```bash
## read each line in file
while IFS= read -r line ; do
...
done
```

2. The "nested" levels associative arrays is clever, but hard to work with - it shows what rabbit holes you can go down with bash - although now when iterating through it, bash produces it in "hash" [order and not the order they were added.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161323/how-to-keep-associative-array-order)

3. Since I actually needed the data in the rest of my script, the nested arrays made it particularly fiddly to deal with. Fine for `printf` purposes where you just print the line, but what if you actually want to *get* the frames count for each item and do then do something with it.

Here was my attempt that simplified it a bit. I implemented it as a bash function which gets a few other bits of info from the sample file:

```bash
TSHARK=/usr/bin/tshark
CAPINFOS=/usr/bin/capinfos

declare -A fcount
declare -A bcount
declare -A capinfo

function loadcapinfo
{
   local sample=$1
   local statstofile=$2
   local bytes
   local frames
   local key

   if [ ! -f "$sample" ] ; then
    echo "FATAL: loadcapinfo: file does not exist: $sample"
    exit 1
   fi

   capinfo[start_time_epoch]=$($CAPINFOS -Tr -Sa $sample | cut -f2)
   capinfo[start_time]=$($CAPINFOS -Tr -a $sample | cut -f2)
   capinfo[end_time_epoch]=$($CAPINFOS -Tr -Se $sample | cut -f2)
   capinfo[end_time]=$($CAPINFOS -Tr -e $sample | cut -f2)
   capinfo[size]=$($CAPINFOS -Tr -s $sample | cut -f2)

   declare -i ln=0

   while IFS= read -r line ; do

    ln=${#line}   # base level on length of line read
    [ $ln -le 1 ] && continue;
    pat=".*frames:([0-9]+)\s+bytes:([0-9]+)"
    pat_1="^(\w+)"
    pat_2="^\s{2}(\w+)"
    pat_3="^\s{4}(\w+)"
    pat_4="^\s{6}(\w+)"
    ethertype="ethertype"

    [[ $line =~ $pat ]]   && { frames=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; bytes=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; } || continue;
    [[ $line =~ $pat_1 ]] && { encap="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}:${ethertype}"; key="${encap}"; }
    [[ $line =~ $pat_2 ]] && { proto=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; key="${encap}:${proto}"; }
    [[ $line =~ $pat_3 ]] && { ptype=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; key="${encap}:${proto}:${ptype}"; }
    [[ $line =~ $pat_4 ]] && { data=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};  key="${encap}:${proto}:${ptype}:${data}"; }

    [ "$proto" = "llc" ]  && { key=${key/eth:ethertype:llc/eth:llc} ; }

    fcount[${key}]=${frames:=0}
    bcount[${key}]=${bytes:=0}

    if [ -n "$statstofile" ] ; then
     echo "${capinfo[start_time_epoch]},${key},${frames},${bytes}" >> $statstofile
    fi

   done < <($TSHARK -qr $sample -z io,phs)

   unset fcount[0]

}
```

Now, after this in the script, we can do:

```
loadcapinfo /my/sample/file.pcap /tmp/stats.txt
```

Optionally write the counts to a file, /tmp/stats.txt

This uses one associative array for each count, and puts other info into `capinfo` so now we can do things like:

```bash
echo "IPv4 Packet Count is: ${fcount[eth:ethertype:ip]}"
echo "IPv6 Packet Count is: ${fcount[eth:ethertype:ipv6]}"
echo "ARP Count is: ${fcount[eth:ethertype:arp]}"
echo "STP Count is: ${fcount[eth:llc:stp]}"

echo "Start time: ${capinfo[start_time]}"
echo "End time: ${capinfo[end_time]}"

echo "File size: ${capinfo[size]}"
```

I made the keys match Wireshark's `frame.protocols` field, which inserts some "pseudo protocol" for most things called "ethertype". This way, if you want to then iterate through the associative array to find the packet(s) in the pcap file, you can use the information to find packets with a given protocol.

```bash
tshark -r /my/sample/file.pcap -Y "frame.protocols == eth:ethertype:ip:udp:snmp" -Tfields -e frame.number -e eth.src_resolved -e eth.dst_resolved -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.protocols
```

```bash
for i in "${!fcount[@]}"; do
        tshark -r /my/sample/file.pcap -Y "frame.protocols == $i" -Tfields -e frame.number -e eth.src_resolved -e eth.dst_resolved -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.protocols > /tmp/$i.txt
done
```