# Execute bash command in batch with mysql results

Tags: mysql, bash

I maintain several servers having the same web app through bash scripts. Commands include basically **ssh** and **scp**, and they are the same for every server, just the IP, the user and the port are different between servers. So far I wrote as many commands as servers to maintain in same script. This works well but as I start to have many servers to maintain, I would prefer to list these servers in a MySQL table, and then use this list in my bash scripts, thus I I would not need to keep all of them updated when I have new servers to maintain.

Currently I have problems to extract data from MySQL in a proper way that could be then executed in bash script.

My current approach is to use CONCAT function in the query as follow:

```sql
outputofquery=$($MYSQL -u"$USER" --batch -p"$PASSWORD" --skip-column-names -h"$HOST" -e "SELECT CONCAT('scp -P ', server_port, ' $file ', server_user, '@', server_ip, ':/var/www/html/site/') FROM server_ssh;" $DBNAME)
echo ${outputofquery%$'\t;'*}
```

Giving the following result:

```
scp -P 22 text.php user1@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html/site/ scp -P 12345 text.php user2@2.2.2.2:/var/www/html/site/
```

Every command resulting from the MySQL query is put on the same line, meaning that this cannot be executed..

I though to add a semicolon just after *site/* in the query, so that even if every command is on the same line, they could be executed independently but it happens that only the last **scp** command gets executed and those before are ignored.

Could you please let me know how I could execute **ssh** and **scp** commands in batch with data coming from a MySQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I succeed to execute batch commands with MySQL data. I build the commands to execute with concatenate function, depending on the line number extracted from MySQL. Below is my script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

HOST="localhost"
USER="root"
DBNAME="mydb"
PASSWORD="mypassord"
MYSQL="/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql"

file='text.php'
i=0;
command='';

ips_and_ports=$($MYSQL -u"$USER" -p"$PASSWORD" -h"$HOST" -BNe "SELECT server_port,server_user,server_ip FROM server_ssh;" $DBNAME)
for line in $ips_and_ports
do
    (( i++ )); #increment the line number

    if [ $(($i % 3)) -eq 1 ] #check if it is the first element of a line extracted from MySQL (server_port)
    then
        command="scp -P $line"; #initialize a new command to execute
    elif [ $(($i % 3)) -eq 2 ] #check if it is the second element of a line extracted from MySQL (server_user)
    then
        command+=" $file $line@"; #concatenate
    elif [ $(($i % 3)) -eq 0 ] #check if it is the third element of a line extracted from MySQL (server_ip)
    then
        command+="$line:/var/www/html/my_web_app/;"; #concatenate
        eval $command; #execute the command 
    fi
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a comment because I'm new.

Have you tried to put a `\n` or `&&` at the end of your mysql concatenation ?

You can also change the approach and assign the server and the port to variables and loop over these variables to execute the `ssh` and the `scp` command. For example

```sh
ips_and_ports=$($MYSQL -u"$USER" --batch -p"$PASSWORD" --skip-column-names -h"$HOST" -e "SELECT server_port, server_ip FROM extranet.server_ssh;" $DBNAME)
for $line in $ips_and_ports
do
    OLDIFS=$IFS;
    IFS="    "; # set the separator to the tab character (PS: this is 4 spaces, change accordingly )
    for $el in $line
    do
        set -- $el; # separate each line by tab and assign the variables to $1, $2 ..
        port=$1;
        ip=$2;
        scp -P 22 text.php user1@$ip:/var/www/html/site/ scp -P $port
    done;
    IFS=$OLDIFS; # put the separator back to it's original value
done;
```

I haven't tested the code but I hope you got my idea !

Good luck

more infos about the IFS and OLDIFS in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713142/11305442)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Unfortunately adding \n or && does not change anything. The approach you describe below is interesting, unfortunately the value in $line includes only one field, not all fields from the SELECT

Comment: I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format) it makes the separator `,` in the query results. the first `for` then loops correctly over lines (you should change $IFS to "," too). The problem I think is that the separator by default is whitespaces of all kind and not `\n` solely

Comment: Thanks, but not better. Anyway, I found a solution by concatenating the command to execute (I put my script in a separate answer) in this thread